Cannot open discover
Tried  to open discover but it diddnt open . The error is :
fetch ratings! true
adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x5f1b73a69f30)

Pls anybody help
OS: Kubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic
DE: Plasma 5.27.11 


Your question is not answerable. Edit your question and add the distro and version of Linux you are using. If it is the desktop or the server version. How you installed Discover? Copy and paste the exact error message from the terminal.

OS: Kubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic
DE: Plasma 5.27.11

OS: Kubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic
DE: Plasma 5.27.11

I've got the same problem and have the same OS, Kernel, and DE.

Similar report at https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/plasma-discover-startet-nicht/

More at https://discuss.kde.org/t/plasma-discover-not-launching/12503/15

Try this:
pkill discover
plasma-discover --backends packagekit-backend

It's not a permanent solution but it's better than nothing. The bug seems to have been fixed for Plasma 6 but the fix hasn't been backported to 5.27. The best ongoing discussion seems to be at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-discover/+bug/2063353

You can also execute plasma-discover --listbackends to know what other backends are installed, and you could also run discover with other backends with the exception of packagekit-backend in a comma-separated list which works as well, for example: plasma-discover --backends snap-backend,flatpak-backend.
